# How does Node Buffer.getIntBE() calculate the negative numbers?

Tags: node.js, binary, buffer, signed

Node buffer reads signed values, but how does it know which algorithm to use? There are three ways, at least, to store a negative number in binary: 2s complement, 1s complement, and traditional.

For example, 1111 could be -7, -0, or -1.

How can Node know how to "unpack" the value and correctly convert it to a negative value? They all LOOK the same, and there's no way to configure when the buffer is initialized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind. Just read [the docs](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html) and Node interprets all signed ints as 2s complement.

Hope this helps someone out in any case.